# How can i update sub document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created one collection using array feature. find the below code.

```
db.timeintimeout.insert({
time_in_time_out_id: 1,
employee_id : 1,
date : new Date(),
timing_details : [{ var: "temp",
time_in : new Date(),
time_out : new Date(),
type: "working hours"}],
active_flag : 1,
created_by : " ",
create_date: new Date(),
modified_by : " ",
modified_date: new Date()
})
```

After created the record, i have selected one unique id var = temp and wrote the update query.

```
db.timeintimeout.update({"employee_id" : 1,"timing_details" : [{"var" : "temp"}]}, {$set: {"timing_details" : [{"var" : "org","time_out" : new Date()}]}})
```

it is showing error. please find the attached screen shot for your reference.

[mongodb update query error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOBLk.png)

when I using sub-document unique code var = temp and write the update query.but it is showing error. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.timeintimeout.update({
    "employee_id": 1,
    "timing_details": {
        $elemMatch: {
            var: 'temp'
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        "timing_details.$.var": "org",
        "timing_details.$.time_out": new Date()
    }
})
```